# How to open a port on google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

On google compute engine, I can access a port on a server through 'localhost',  but I can not access the same port using IP address from the same server or from external client machines. I tried to create a new firewall rule on web console page, and can see it from Linux command, but port 8888 still can't be accessed

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES    RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS
allow8888               default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:8888,udp:8888
default-allow-http      default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:80                                  http-server
default-allow-https     default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:443                                 https-server
```

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved by changing local tcp server setting files
from 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0'

Comment: hey! where is these files located in order to change them?

Comment: the edit suggestion is at /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing local tcp server setting files from 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0'

goto etc/hosts and update your host entries it should work