# Open up specific ports in google compute Engine. [centos7]

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform, firewall, iptables

I am trying to open up some ports on my compute VM.

For example, I have this in `firewall-rules`

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES    RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS
default-allow-http      default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:80                                  http-server
default-allow-https     default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:443                                 https-server
default-allow-icmp      default  0.0.0.0/0     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  10.128.0.0/9  tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:22
test-24284              default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:24284                               test-tcp-open-24284
```

I have created a centos 7 instance to which I have attached the tags

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe test-network-opened
...
...
  items:
  - http-server
  - https-server
  - test-tcp-open-24284
...
...
```

Now when I try to check from my dev box to see whether the port is opened or not using `nmap` on the public IP showed in the console for the VM

```
$ nmap -p 24284 35.193.xxx.xxx

Nmap scan report for 169.110.xxx.xx.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.193.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.25s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
24284/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.15 seconds
```

Now it's hitting the external `NAT IP` for my VM which would be `169.110.xxx.xx`

I tried checking using the `iptables` rules, but that didn't show anything

```
[root@test-network-opened ~]# iptables -S | grep 24284
[root@test-network-opened ~]#
```

So I enabled `firewalld` and tried opening the port with it

```
[root@test-network-opened ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=24284/tcp --permanent
success
[root@test-network-opened ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
success
[root@test-network-opened ~]# iptables -S | grep 24284
[root@test-network-opened ~]#
```

I am not sure where I am doing it wrong with this. I referred these relevant questions on SO about this

- [How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)
- [Can't open port 8080 on Google Compute Engine running Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880703/cant-open-port-8080-on-google-compute-engine-running-debian)
- [How to open a port on google compute engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088370/how-to-open-a-port-on-google-compute-engine)
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/describe

Comment: Is there any service running on port `24284` on your VM? Please post output of `netstat -plnt` command.

Answer (score 1):

The ports were opened by the firewall but since I didn't have an application using the port already, `nmap` was showing the closed port which meant it was able to reach to the server and not firewalled

If it was it would have showed filtered.

I didn't have any application running on it so, didn't know this as a possibility. Careless of me.

Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Glad that it helped.